# Как утановить ограничение времени на fsockopen

Tags: php

Проблема такая: скрипт стучится к неправильному IP слишком долго (>30s).

```
private function connect($ip, $port) {
    $connection = @fsockopen("udp://" . $ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 0.05);
    stream_set_timeout(5);
    if(!$connection) return false;
    stream_set_blocking($connection, true);
    return $connection;
}
private function query($connection, $query, $append = "") {
    if(!$connection) return false;
    $command = pack("c*", 0xFE, 0xFD, $query, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01) . $append;
    $length = strlen($command);
    fwrite($connection, $command, $length);
    $data = fread($connection, 4096);
    return substr($data, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вас варнинг вида

> stream_set_timeout() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

совершенно не смущает? [stream_set_timeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) требуется ставить на ресурс, это не глобальная штука и у этой функции 2 обязательных аргумента. Соответственно вы запрашиваете таймаут на `fsockopen` последним параметром - но это UDP, там нет установки соединения вовсе. Поэтому не уверен, может ли `fsockopen` по UDP вообще отвалиться по таймауту. Похожим образом сложно таймаут ждать от fwrite. UDP никак не подтвердит, что пакет получен. Можно послать пакет и всё, больше ждать нечего. Но fwrite с сетью всё-таки работает, так что тут таймаут ещё может быть при отправке. Ждёт же скрипт на `fread`. И поскольку `stream_set_timeout` был вызван некорректно - то таймаут используется дефолтный.

Вот если корректно запросить `stream_set_timeout`

```
stream_set_timeout($connection, 5);
```

То последующий `fread` будет учитывать этот таймаут и прервётся по прошествии этого времени.